# Tangent Line Between Two Functions

Tags: python-3.x, system, derivative

Given two functions I want to find the tangent line(s) between them. The formula/system for this, if given two arbitrary functions f(x) and g(x), is:

```
f(x)-x*f'(x)-g(y)+y*g'(y)=0
f'(x)-g'(y)=0
```

where when solved, say x=a and y=b, gives two points: (a,f(a)) and (b,g(b)), such that a line can be drawn between them.
The functions I want to find the tangent line between are x^-x and its first derivative (x^-x(-ln(x)-1)).
The code I have is:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt

n=1
s1,s2=sp.symbols('s1 s2')

def f1(z1):
return z1**-z1


def myFunction(z):
   x=z[0]
   y=z[1]
   q1=f1(s1)-s1*sp.diff(f1(s1),s1,n)- 
   sp.diff(f1(s2),s2,n)+s2*sp.diff(f1(s2),s2,n+1)
   q2=sp.diff(f1(s1),s1,n)-sp.diff(f1(s2),s2,n+1)

   F=np.empty((2))
   F[0]=abs(q1.subs([(s1,x),(s2,y)]))
   F[1]=abs(q2.subs([(s1,x),(s2,y)]))
   return F
zGuess=np.array([0.6,1.3])
z=opt.fsolve(myFunction, zGuess)
print(z)
```

The solution should be x=0.59515 and y=1.37866 but it says "Can't calculate 1st derivative wrt 0.6". I don't know how to have it input the initial values for solving the system after taking the derivative with respect to x and y respectively. How would I get it to solve for these values while being able to change n so that the tangent line can also be found between the first derivative and second derivative and so on? Here is a picture showing what it looks like.[image: Tangent Line Between Functions]

Comment: Hey @Mr. T, I realized I had to use a dummy variable for the differentiation and then use the subs function to get it in terms of x and y but now it is saying "can't convert complex to float". These functions are complicated but are not complex. (i.e. real and imaginary) Can python even solve long equations like these? These are what the equations of the system look like.                                    -x*x**(-x)*(-log(x) - 1) + y*y**(-y)*((log(y) + 1)**2 - 1/y) - y**(-y)*(-log(y) - 1) + x**(-x) ,
    -y**(-y)*((log(y) + 1)**2 - 1/y) + x**(-x)*(-log(x) - 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem. Here is the solution below.

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as opt
s1,s2=sp.symbols('s1 s2')

def f1(z1):
    return z1**-z1

def myFunction(z,n):
    x=z[0]
    y=z[1]

    if n % 2 ==0:
        w1=1
        w2=-1

    else:
        w1=-1
        w2=1
    q1=w2*sp.diff(f1(s1),s1,n-1)-w2*s1*sp.diff(f1(s1),s1,n)- 
w1*sp.diff(f1(s2),s2,n)+w1*s2*sp.diff(f1(s2),s2,n+1)
    q2=w2*sp.diff(f1(s1),s1,n)-w1*sp.diff(f1(s2),s2,n+1)

    F=np.empty((2))
    F[0]=abs(q1.subs([(s1,x),(s2,y)]))
    F[1]=abs(q2.subs([(s1,x),(s2,y)]))
    return F


j1=1
j2=10
z=np.empty((j2+1,2))
for i in range(j1,j2+1):
    n=i
    a=float(0.5211*n+0.184)
    b=float(0.916745*a+0.794333)
    zGuess=np.array([a,b])
    z[i,:]=opt.fsolve(myFunction, zGuess, n, maxfev = 6000)
    print(z[i,:])
```

This solution gives the first ten pairs of points. The output when done is

```
[ 0.59515445  1.37866112]
[ 1.19255583  1.87697191]
[ 1.75662656  2.37914507]
[ 2.29484826  2.87469058]
[ 2.81278951  3.36119549]
[ 3.31426591  3.83840029]
[ 3.80198665  4.30671276]
[ 4.277955    4.76673553]
[ 4.74370426  5.21909897]
[ 5.20044161  5.66440097]
```